# float vs. inline-block changes margin and parent height

Tags: html, css, css-float

So I have been trying to wrap my mind around this and cant figure it out why.

**Note**: Margin and padding is 0.

***The 1st example is***

```
<div> <!-- Gray Box -->
   <div> <!-- Purple Box -->

   </div>
</div>
```

I have two images - One is float, the other is inline-block.

The height of the div is shown by the gray color.

```
float: left;
```

[image: Float]

```
display: inline-block;
```

[image: inline]

***The 2nd example is***

```
<div>
  <ul>
    <a href = "#">
      <li>
        <img src = "...">
      </li>
    </a>
  </ul>
</div>
```

Again, left and inline-block do different things

```
float: left;
```

[image: left]

```
display: inline-block;
```

[image: block]

**Bottom Line**

Any suggestions beside the question is welcome.
I don't know why margin / padding is changing and why div size matters by float and display. Thanks

Comment: The problem is that with `inline-block`, whitespace matters - the spaces between the divs is what looks like a margin.

Comment: Try putting all the divs on one line, with no spaces between `</div>` and `<div>`, and you'll see what I mean.

Comment: Here is a fiddle that demonstrates ul vs div with various formats http://jsfiddle.net/4wwvtq4d/. The floats, by definition float to the farthest point left (no space) where in-line block always gives a small margin that can be removed in a variety of ways - http://css-tricks.com/fighting-the-space-between-inline-block-elements/

Answer (score 0):

There are 2 problems here.

1) Like someone mentioned in the comments, inline block takes space into account, meaning on the parent div you should have:

```
font-size:0;
```

2) **Floating takes the element out of the document flow**, meaning the parent will expand only past the last non floated child element. To fix this you should put a clearfix class in your css and add it to the parent of the floated element(s).

```
.clearfix::after{
   content:'';
   display:block;
   clear:both;
}
```

So once you've done this your first example should look like this:

```
<div class="clearfix"> <!-- Gray Box -->
   <div style="float:left"> <!-- Purple Box -->
   </div>
</div>
```

Now the gray box should expand past the purple box;
As a matter of consistency i don't think you should mix inline-block with floating. One, it won't work on the same element and 2, they are designed for different things.